# Error: 'no pg_hba.conf entry for host' using Django with PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, azure

I am building a web app using Django. I am trying to connect the app to the Azure Database for PostgreSQL.

When I try to make migrations with the command, `python manage.py makemigrations` from PowerShell, I'm getting this error:

`no pg_hba.conf entry for host`

What does this error mean?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! To allow people to help you, please consider reading this link about [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Particularly the need to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2):

This error means you've haven't configured PostgreSQL correctly for the user you are trying to connect from Django with.

`pg_hba.conf` is the PostgreSQL file which contains PostgreSQL users, where from, and how they are able to connect. See here for more details:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

You should get the same error when you try to run any Django command which needs to connect to the database, for example, `python manage.py dbshell`. Good luck!

Comment: I am trying to connect to Azure Database for PostgreSQL. I followed all the steps to get the database on azure up and running. If the database is working then, how can I not have configured it correctly?